# php mysql user info update

Tags: php, mysql

```
if ($email != $CURUSER["email"]) {
if (!validemail($email))
    bark( _("Klaida! Panašu, kad klaidingai įvedei email adresą!") );
$r = do_mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=" . sqlesc($email)) or sqlerr();
if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0)
    bark( sprintf( _("Toks emailas adresas %s jau naudojamas!"), $email) );
           ####
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $modcomment_email = "{$date} - E-mail pakeistas, pakeitė: {$CURUSER['username']}";
    $modcomment_email = mysql_real_escape_string($modcomment_email);
    do_mysql_query("UPDATE users SET modcomment = '$modcomment_email' where id = ".$CURUSER['id']) or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__);
          #####
$changedemail = 1;
 }
```

After this script executed row updated, but old data deleted. How update row, but keep old data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an `UPDATE` command.  This does, as you've observed, modify the row(s) that match your `WHERE` clause.

If you'd like to keep the list of previous `$modcomment_emails` then you'll need to use an `INSERT` into some table and then make sure you're selecting the most recent record out when you do your `SELECT` to output the data.  You could add a column to keep the date of the insert as something to `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the old data, you would have to move a copy into an archive table, by issuing the "update" command it overwrites anything that was there. Example

if I have a table where username is "Bugfinder" and now, I change the username to "Bug" there will be no reference to Bugfinder because it was overwritten. If I wanted to keep that, I would need to have copied the line into an archive table maybe a long with the date/time of change, so I could look back historically for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - if you want to insert new row use `INSERT` if want to update use `UPDATE`. Also solution is to create history table when you would drop needed old date with the time when change happend